# Jquery Select .prepend("<option></option>") not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-blade

The problem i am having is loading a select box and showing the placeholder when nothing is selected.

Using select2 (4.0.1) works only if i set as "multiple"

```
{!! Form::select('meals_list', $meals, $mealSelected, ['id' =>'meals_list_'.$dayId, 'class'=>'form-control', 'style'=>'width: 100%', 'multiple', 'data-placeholder'=>'Select now']) !!}
```

The js

```
    $('#meals_list_'+dayId).prepend("<option></option>");
    $('#meals_list_'+dayId).select2({
        placeholder: 'Select a meal...'
        // allowClear: true
    });
```

as soon as i remove multiple, select is defaulting to the first item, which is not `<option></option>` and in fact `<option></option>` is never added in the rendered html.

so why is prepend not working in jquery?

Comment: did you read the documentation fro prepend?, why not use append?

Comment: Maybe you dont understand the requirement?

Comment: you want a option in a select  that will be a select2 element

Comment: using prepend you appending it as a sibling of select so your first option element wil **not** be `"<option></option>"`

Comment: wouldn't .append() be appending?

Comment: yes it will insert the option tag in the select tag

Answer (score 0):

More of a work around.
Adding **maximumSelectionLength: 1** achieved what i wanted.

```
    $('#meals_list_'+dayId).select2({
        placeholder: 'Select a meal...',
        maximumSelectionLength: 1
        // allowClear: true
    });
```